# Proof $f$ has a minimum if $f$ is continuous and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(f(x))=\infty=\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}(f(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification

I have a question about the validity of this proof I wrote:

**Claim**: If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(f(x))=\infty=\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}(f(x))$, then $f$ has a minimum.

**My proof**:

Lower Bound Theorem) If $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $\exists z \in [a,b]: \forall x \in [a,b]: f(z)\leq f(x)$

(1) $\forall N_1: \exists n_1>0: \text{if } x>n_1 \text{ then } f(x)>N_1$ (Definition)

(2) $\forall N_2: \exists n_2<0: \text{if } x<n_2 \text{ then } f(x)>N_2$ (Definition)

(3) Given $N_1, N_2$: Let $I = [n_2, n_1]$

(4) $\therefore f$ is continuous on $I$

(5) $\therefore \exists y \in I: \forall x \in I:f(y) \leq f(x)$ (Using Lower Bound Theorem)

(6) If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ but $x \notin I$, then $x < n_2$ or $x>n_1$.

(7) $\therefore f(x) > N_1$ or $f(x) > N_2$

(8) Choose $N_1, N_2: f(y)<N_1$ and $f(y)<N_2$

(9) $\therefore \forall x \in \mathbb{R}:f(y) \leq f(x)$

Thanks for reading. I'm not sure about line 8. I already defined $N_1$ and $N_2$ in line 3, and constructed $y$ based on that in line 5. So if I redefine $N_1$ and $N_2$ based on $y$ in line 8, that could potentially redefine $y$ in line 5, which could redefine $N_1$ and $N_2$ in line 8, which could redefine $y$ in line 5, etc. etc. I'm pretty sure either this is just a little technicality that can be fixed easily but I'm not sure how, or it's not a problem at all and I'm overthinking. Can someone help?

Comment: Indeed, there is a problem in the order you define your $N$'s and $n$'s. A way to fix that would be to choose (at lign $3$) $N_1$ and $N_2$ greater that $f(0)+1$. Doing that, you know that $0$ belongs to $[n_1, n_2]$, and then $f(y) \leq f(0)$, and then the property of your lign $8$ is correct.

Comment: All the things , you have done, it seems ok to me.

Comment: @Alearner No, it's not. He first defines $N_1$, $N_2$. Then depending on $N_1$ and $N_2$, he defines $I$. Then depending on $I$, he defines $y$. Then depending on $y$, he defines $N_1$ and $N_2$...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Hmm, op should be careful to choose $N_{1},N_{2}$, just take atleast one functional value which is less than both of $N_{1},N_{2}$, this can be easily assumed by taking $N_{1},N_{2}$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @Alearner This is what I said in my first comment. The proof can easily be fixed, but written as it is, it has a logical issue.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe the main problem is with the order of those lines made by op.

Comment: @Alearner Thank you for rewritting exactly what I said previoulsy.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I don't understand what you mean. 0 definitely is in $[n_2, n_1]$ since $n_1>0$ and $n_2<0$. But even if it weren't, where does $f(0) + 1$ and $f(y) \leq f(0)$ come from?

Comment: @SenZen The problem in your proof is what you wrote at the end of your question : you first (lign $3$) define $N_1$ and $N_2$, then **depending on** them you define $n_1$ and $n_2$, then depending on them you define $y$, then depending on $y$ you define $N_1$ and $N_2$. This is circular, so incorrect. A way to fix it is to define *at the beginning* the $N_1$ and $N_2$ that will work. A way to do that is to define them greater that any value of $f$ (for example $f(0)$) : by doing this, in your line $8$, $N_1$ and $N_2$ are already greater that $f(y)$ and you don't have to re-choose them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative, let consider the restriction $f:[a,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ then if $f(a)$ is not a minimum for the restriction by IVT $\exists b>a$ such that $f(b)=f(a)$ and $f(x)\ge f(b) \,\forall x\ge b$, then by EVT the restriction attains a minimum $f(c)$ at $c\in [a,b]$.

We can use the same argument for the restriction $f:(-\infty,a] \to \mathbb R$ to show that the restriction attains a minimum $f(c')$ at $c'\in [b',a]$.

Then $$\min (f(x))=\min(f(c),f'(c))$$

Comment: I'm not so sure about the $f(x)\ge f(b) \,\forall x\ge b$. This is true, but only because $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(f) = \infty$, which needs to be invoked in your proof. And how to invoke it to get $f(x)\ge f(b) \,\forall x\ge b$ isn't trivial to me?

Comment: @SenZen Yes I'm referring exactly to that of course, even if not esplicitely said. it is a trace for a full proof. By IVT exists such $b$ and by the definition of limit there must be a maximum value for $b$ which is the one we are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see that result is the following. I just give the lines of the proof, one can prove the details by itself : consider
$$A = f^{-1}\left((-\infty, f(0)]\right)$$

1. $A$ is closed.
2. $A$ is bounded, because $\lim_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x) = +\infty$.

So $A$ is compact, so $f$ has a minimum on $A$.

3. this minimum is a global minimum of $f$.

Comment: I'm not sure. What if the minimum of $f$ is (say) $f(1)$?

Comment: What is the problem in that case ?

Comment: You say that the minimum on $A$ is the global minimum, while it might not be there.

Comment: A point $x$ where $f$ attains its global minimum satisfies $f(x) \leq f(0)$, so of course $x$ must belong to $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument can be modified as follows.

Let $N$ be any positive number such that $N>f(0).$ By the given assumptions, there exist $n_1>0$ and $n_2<0$ such that $$f(x)>N,\forall x>n_1$$ and $$f(x)>N,\forall x<n_2.$$

Since $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, $f$ is continuous on $[n_2,n_1]$. By Weierstrass’s Theorem (or the Lower Bound Theorem in your proof), $$\exists z\in [n_2,n_1] ~{\rm such~that~}f(z)\leq f(x),\forall x\in [n_2,n_1].$$ In particular $f(z)\leq f(0)<N.$ Clearly $f(z)$ is the minimum of $f$ on $\mathbb R$. QED

Answer (score -1):

Let $x_0$ be some point in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x)=\infty$ and $f$ is  continuous, there exists an $M>0$ such that $$f(x_1)>f(x_0)$$ for any $x$ satisfying $|x|>M$. Since any minimizer $x^*$ of $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x^*)\leq f(x_0)$, it follows that the set of minimizers of $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is the same as the set over $\mathbb{R}\cap B_{|\cdot|}[0,M]$, which is compact and non-empty. This is because both $\mathbb{R}, B_{|\cdot|}[0,M]$ are closed and $B$ is bounded and contains $x_0$. Therefore by Weierstrass Theorem for closed functions, there exists a minimizer of $f$ over $\mathbb{R}\cap B_{|\cdot|}[0,M]$ and hence also over $\mathbb{R}$.

**P.S.**

The above holds for every coercive function $f$ and closed non-empty set $S$.